# R timeDate package - holidays output issue

Tags: r, datetime, calendar

I need to make a list of holidays that includes NYSE holidays plus Columbus Day and Veterans Day. For that I used `timeDate` package as follows:

```
library(timeDate)
years <- 2015

holidayEIA <- function(x){ c(holidayNYSE(x),
                             as.Date(USColumbusDay(x)),
                             as.Date(USVeteransDay(x))) }
holidayEIA(years)
```

The output includes two dates in 1969. It also adds a time next to the date. I could strip the time stamp and elements containing 1969 with a line of code. Yet, would prefer those to not be present from the very beginning.

```
#Output
[1] [2015-01-01 00:00:00] [2015-01-19 00:00:00] [2015-02-16 00:00:00]
[4] [2015-04-03 00:00:00] [2015-05-25 00:00:00] [2015-07-03 00:00:00]
[7] [2015-09-07 00:00:00] [2015-11-26 00:00:00] [2015-12-25 00:00:00]
[10] [1969-12-31 23:38:40] [1969-12-31 23:39:10]
```

If I run `holidayNYSE(2015)`, `USColumbusDay(2015)` or `USVeteransDay(2015)` separately the resulting timeDate objects have no time stamp, and there is no year 1969. I do not understand why running all three together results in a time stamp added and in the 1969 issue. Of course I could also run the three independently and them bind them. That's just a patch; I'd rather not have to do that if I can avoid it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Removing `as.Date()` from the function seems to produce the correct dates, but yet with the timestamp. That is perhaps due to Timezone issues. `holidayNYSE` is referencing New York, whereas other two are GMT.

Comment: Actually, if you look at the timeDate object, it has an attribute Data, which has the correct date value. So, access it as `c(holidayNYSE(x), USColumbusDay(x)@Data, USVeteransDay(x)@Data)`. Still GMT.

Comment: Thank you Gopala. That corrected the wrong dates (1969 issue) but still get the time stamp. The issue is the Timezone as you suggested. `timeDate` notices the different Timezones and provides "[2015-10-11 20:00:00] [2015-11-10 19:00:00]" as output for `USColumbusDay(2015)` and `USVeteransDay(2015)` (i.e. moved to the day before GMT time). So guess there is no solution but to run them separately and bind them, or run them jointly and eliminate the time afterwards. Want to put this as answer?

Comment: Yeah, there is no `tz` option in these. So, stripping or converting to `posixct` with proper timezone seems like the right idea. I don't think there is much I did to write it up as an answer. At least, we figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved both issues:

```
library(timeDate)
years <- 2015

holidayEIA <- function(x){ c(holidayNYSE(x), 
                             USColumbusDay(x)@Data+ 14400, 
                             USVeteransDay(x)@Data+ 18000)}
holidayEIA(years)
```